# How I can use IMAPS in XPages

Tags: xpages, imap

I want to build a XPage to retrieve eMails with JavaMail. There is no problem connecting to servers with the imap provider (eg. session.getStore("imap")). But now I want to connect to a mail sever via imaps (session.getStore("imaps")). All I get is an excepction "NoSouchProvider".

If I take a look at the provider that are registred with the session, there are only POP3, SMTP and IMAP; no IMAPS.

Is there a way to use IMAPS with XPages? What alternative do I have?

BTW: Domino server is 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [modified classes](https://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/) that make IMAP compatible with gMail and use this code:

```java
private GmailSSLStore getStore() throws MessagingException {
    if (this.store != null) {
        return this.store;
     }
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.connectiontimeout", "5000");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", "imap.gmail.com");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.timeout", "5000");
    props.setProperty("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "gimaps");

    javax.mail.Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    this.store = (GmailSSLStore) session.getStore("gimaps");
    this.store.connect(this.userName, this.passWord);
    // Ready for connection ;-)
    return this.store;
}
```

You can modify that code to adjust it to your needs. Hope that helps

Comment: I will try your solution further. But right at the moment I have two problems: Problem one: if I call System.getProperties() in my XPage I get a security exception, that I'm not allowed to access the properites. I know I can edit the java.policy but that's not an option for my customer. So is there another solution? The second problem: your suggestion extends JavaMail 1.4.4 but the domino server uses JavaMail 1.3. Can I simply use this extension?

Comment: Easiest way would be to a Package your Java code into an OSGi plugin. Sorts the security problem and you can add the mods

Comment: Building an OSGi plugin might be a solution. But then, how do I call the java classes in this plugin from my XPage? Calling any classes within the plugin cause a "Class not found"-Exception in my XPage.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IMAP provider and require javamail's STARTTLS property (IIRC it was a property).

Comment: I should perhaps elaborate. STARTTLS is an IMAP command to start encrypting an until that point cleartext IMAP session. Starttls is commonly used as the first command.